# Assign different logger (appender) to different Apache Camel routes?

Tags: spring, logging, log4j, apache-camel, log4j2

I was wondering if there is any way already implemented in Apache Camel to be able to log to different loggers depending on the route. I am using Spring DSL to create the routes. My use case is that I want a different log file for each route I am defining.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enabled MDC logging, which then include details about which route is currently being logged from: http://camel.apache.org/mdc-logging.html

Then the logging framework you use, such as log4j, logback, etc. can be configured to log to different appenders based on a MDC key (eg camel.routeId)

Comment: Thanks for answer Claus! I am going to use MDC logging and Log4j2 RoutingAppender to achieve that.